# software-properties-gtk not working opening in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center, gtk

When I tried opening it via terminal, it returns the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 37, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.gtk.SoftwarePropertiesGtk import SoftwarePropertiesGtk
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 35, in <module>
    from aptdaemon import client
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1570
    async = reply_handler and error_handler
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Have you changed python (version) defaults?  What do you get with `python -V; python3 -V` ?

Comment: @guiverc I am running Python 2.7.15+ and Python 3.7.4+ respectively.

Comment: Any update on this one?
having the same issue

python -V; python3 -V
Python 2.7.16
Python 3.7.3